# Why doesn't IntelliSense recognize variable arguments?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using IntelliSense in VSCode for C, and I find it unable to recognize variable arguments. For example:

```
#define printk_warning_nbk(module, mnemonic, fmt, args...)
```

IntelliSense would always add error squiggles under the `...` saying `expected a ')'`.

How can I make it parse variable arguments?

Comment: That is because the syntax is `printk_warning_nbk(module, mnemonic, fmt, ...)` (so no word `args` before the `...`).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks for the reply. But according to gnu doc using `args...` in macro is legal: If your macro is complicated, you may want a more descriptive name for the variable argument than __VA_ARGS__. CPP permits this, as an extension. You may write an argument name immediately before the ‘…’; that name is used for the variable argument. The eprintf macro above could be written
`#define eprintf(args…) fprintf (stderr, args)`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I just realized it says it's an extension... so maybe Intellisense just doesn't support this feature. Thanks again.